# XMLType pl/sql update child

Tags: xml, oracle10g

i have XML structure like below in XMLType column (Oracle 10g)

```
  <DATA>
  <CHILDRENS>
    <CHILDRENS_DEF lname="smith">
      <CHILD_KOL no="1" name="Id" desc="Id" typ="NUMBER"/>
      <CHILD_KOL no="2" name="Fname" desc="Fname" typ="VARCHAR2"/>
    </CHILDRENS_DEF>
    <CHILDRENS_DATA>
      <CHILD_DATA no="1">
        <CHILD_COL_VALUE no="1" name="Id">1</CHILD_COL_VALUE>
        <CHILD_COL_VALUE no="2" name="Fname">Christopher</CHILD_COL_VALUE>
      </CHILD_DATA>
      <CHILD_DATA no="2">
        <CHILD_COL_VALUE no="1" name="Id">1</CHILD_COL_VALUE>
        <CHILD_COL_VALUE no="2" name="Fname">Alice</CHILD_COL_VALUE>
      </CHILD_DATA>
      <CHILD_DATA no="3">
        <CHILD_COL_VALUE no="1" name="Id">1</CHILD_COL_VALUE>
        <CHILD_COL_VALUE no="2" name="Fname">John</CHILD_COL_VALUE>
      </CHILD_DATA>
    </CHILDRENS_DATA>
  </CHILDRENS>
  <CHILDRENS>
    <CHILDRENS_DEF lname="mushroom">
      <CHILD_KOL no="1" name="Id" desc="Id" typ="NUMBER"/>
      <CHILD_KOL no="2" name="Fname" desc="Fname" typ="VARCHAR2"/>
    </CHILDRENS_DEF>
    <CHILDRENS_DATA>
      <CHILD_DATA no="1">
        <CHILD_COL_VALUE no="1" name="Id">1</CHILD_COL_VALUE>
        <CHILD_COL_VALUE no="2" name="Fname">Arthur</CHILD_COL_VALUE>
      </CHILD_DATA>
    </CHILDRENS_DATA>
  </CHILDRENS>
</DATA>
```

How I can update child name, where CHILDRENS_DEF lname=smith and CHILD_DATA no=2 ??

Comment: did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [updateXML](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96620/xdb04cre.htm#1032612),
the XPATH expression should look somewhat like this:

```
DATA/CHILDRENS[CHILDRENS_DEF/@lname="smith"]/CHILDRENS_DATA/CHILD_DATA[@no="2"]/CHILD_COL_VALUE[@name="Fname"]/text()
```

If you want to update the column in the table it should look like this:

```
UPDATE <<your_table>>
SET <<xml_col_name>> = updateXML(<<xml_col_name>>,
                                 'DATA/CHILDRENS[CHILDRENS_DEF/@lname="smith"]/CHILDRENS_DATA/CHILD_DATA[@no="2"]/CHILD_COL_VALUE[@name="Fname"]/text()',
                                 'AB');
```

Comment: When I tried this I got error message:

ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qmcxdUnpicLoc9], [20], [28], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Comment: did you try it from sql*plus or some tool (ie sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper etc.) ?

Comment: I'm using pl/sql developer v. 7.1.5.1398

Comment: Then try it from sql*plus, I suspect it's a problem in plsqldeveloper and not in the query.

Comment: Ok I tested this. In 10g all its ok only on 11g i have this problem.
In SqlPlus:
Connected.
SQL> UPDATE xml_children
  2  SET xml_data = updateXML(xml_data,
  3                                   'DATA/CHILDRENS[CHILDRENS_DEF/@lname="smit
h"]/CHILDRENS_DATA/CHILD_DATA[@no="2"]/CHILD_COL_VALUE[@name="Fname"]/text()',
  4                                   'AB');
UPDATE xml_children
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qmcxdUnpicLoc9], [20], [28], [],
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Comment: I've run it on 11g and it works fine. From what found in the internet, it's a plsqldeveloper problem ([20] is the error code). maybe you can open another post for this exception. BTW, when I tried it (with plsqldev) with a `select` statement (not the update) I managed to workaround with `getClobVal()` function (I mean- `select updateXML(<<xml_col_name>>, ...).getClobVal() from dual;`