# Update a XML tag in my Oracle database row

Tags: xml, oracle

I want to create a trigger, which updates a single node in my xml file. I have a table with 2 rows, where one is the id of the entry and the other one is a xml type

```
drop table product_information_xml;
create table product_information_xml(
information_id Number(6,0),
products XMLType);
```

So, now one entry looks like this

```
"INFORMATION_ID"    "PRODUCTS"
5                  <products>
                       <product_id>1</product_id>
                       <product_name>samsung galaxy note</product_name>
                       <product_description>mobile phone</product_description>
                       <category_id>11</category_id>
                       <weight_class>2</weight_class>
                       <warranty_period>+000000000-06</warranty_period>
                       <supplier_id>102069</supplier_id>
                       <product_status>orderable</product_status>
                  <list_price>500</list_price>
                  <min_price>400</min_price>
                  <catalog_url>www.samsung.de</catalog_url>
              </products>
```

So now I have another table which isn't xml. And has all XML tags as single columns. So the columns are `product_id`, `product_description` etc.

When I update the `product_id` how do I update the xml node `<product_id>` in the xml table? Can anybody help?

What I know yet is that I start with

```
Create or replace trigger delete_xml
after update on product_information
for each row
begin
update ?????
end;
```

Now I am stuck. I would love for help!

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867839/xmltype-pl-sql-update-child

Comment: Hi. Yes I saw it already, but the problem is, that I need it in a trigger. Thats where I am stuck. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know which node you'll update, maybe it will be easyier for you to update the whole XMLTYPE-

```
update product_information_xml
   set products = xmltype('<products><product_id>'||:new.product_id||'</product_id>'||
                   '<product_name>'|| :new.product_name||'</product_name>'||
                   '<product_description>'|| :new.product_description||'</product_description>'||
                   '<category_id>'|| :new.category_id||'</category_id>'||
                   '<weight_class>'|| :new.weight_class||'</weight_class>'||
                   '<warranty_period>'|| :new.warranty_period||'</warranty_period>'||
                   '<supplier_id>'|| :new.supplier_id||'</supplier_id>'||
                   '<product_status>'|| :new.product_status||'</product_status>'||
                   '<list_price>'|| :new.list_price||'</list_price>'||
                   '<min_price>'|| :new.min_price||'</min_price>'||
                   '<catalog_url>'|| :new.catalog_url||'</catalog_url></products>')
 where information_id = :new.information_id;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks, this worked nearly perfect. Just changed the last line to
`code` where (SELECT p.products.extract('/products/product_id/text()').getStringVal() "ProductID"
FROM product_information_xml p) = :new.product_id;
 end;

So. The problem now is just, when I have the same product id several times. I get the error that my where clause from the update

update product_information
set list_price=400
where product_id = 1

returns more than one row. But the product_id shouldn't be unique. So this is the only thing I have to fix

Answer (score 0):

right so the statement in the trigger would be like this:

if product_id is not nullable:

```
update product_information_xml
     set products = updatexml(products, '/products/product_id/text()', :new.product_id)
   where information_id = :new.information_id;
```

if it is, use a longer way (as updatexml wont work going from NULL to non NULL:

```
update product_information_xml
     set products = insertxmlbefore(deletexml(products, '/products/product_id'), 
                         '/products/product_name', 
                        xmltype('<product_id>' || :new.product_id|| '</product_id>'))
   where information_id = :new.information_id;
```

Comment: Hi. at first, thanks for your comment, but the problem is that I don't know what I have to do if I need to update something else. I mean I have 10 tags in my xml. Now I can update the product_id. But what do I do when I want to update the product_description? I know that I just have to change the product_id to product_description in your example, but the trigger should know from itself which node to be updated.